# Problemas al intentar leer el archivo dbf en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo dbf en C#, pero primero tuve el error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The provider' Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 'is not registered on the local machine.'

Luego instalé Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable y ahora tengo el error

> The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file 'C:\Users\Emmanuel\Desktop\Proyectos\program'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.'

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```cs
var constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
var sql = "select * from " + file;
var ds = new DataTable();

using (var con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
{
    con.Open();

    using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con))
    {
        using (var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
    }
}
```

También he intentado esto pero tengo este error

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft] [ODBC dBase Driver] The external table is not in the expected format.'

```cs
string fullPath = path + file;
string sConn = "Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=" + path + ";Exclusive=No; NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;";

using (OdbcConnection dbConn = new OdbcConnection(sConn))
{
    dbConn.Open();
    OdbcCommand oCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
    oCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + fullPath;

    /* Load data to table */

    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Load(oCmd.ExecuteReader());
    dbConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Comprueba que el .MDF no sea de Solo Lectura.

Comment: También ábrelo con MS Access y asegúrate de que sea legible.